# CSS expanding div's

Tags: html, css

Hi my CSS code is this:

```
        #bottom {

             height: 100px;
             background-color: #afafaf;   
             width: auto;
             border-top: 4px solid green;
             margin-top: 90px;

        }
```

my code is this:

```
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">      
        <div id="logo"></div>           
    </div>

        <a href=""><div class="box">Go to our forums &raquo; </div></a>

        <div id="bottom">TEST</div>

</body>
```

This is what it looks like: http://screencloud.net/v/cxEu

why does it show those gaps on both ends of the div? I want it to show across the whole screen. I tried different widths, but nothing works. Or I'm doing something wrong !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the body's margins, try this:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify `margin: 0` and `padding: 0`:

```
#bottom {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #afafaf;   
  width: auto;
  border-top: 4px solid green;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 90px;
}
```